# How to create a target in Xcode 4 with AppleScript?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, applescript

I would like to create a `Target` in Xcode 4 by using `AppleScript`, normally when I press the 'Add Target' button a window prompts me to choose which kind of target I need. I would like to create an `Empty Application target` (Empty Application is an option at least in my iOS based app).

Could anyone help me out here ?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Didn't find a solution... apparently there's no way to do so... did you find a workaround?

Comment: After researching online for a couple of days, it became obvious that AppleScript is broken in Xcode 4. Apparently, there was some functionality that worked in Xcode 3, but there is even less in Xcode 4. What I ended up doing is reading the .pbxproj file (which is inside the .xcodeproj file, which is actually a folder, not a file) using NSPropertyListSerializer. Once I populated some Objective-C classes I created, I manipulated the project and re-wrote back into the old-style plist format (ASCII plist) style it is in using GNUStep. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @Roberto you could post an answer to the question, it would be great to document your findings.